# Shadows in UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In a `UINavigationController` stack, how can I change the topmost viewController´s layer attributes, like `.view.layer.shadowRadius`?

In other words, I´d need to change the default shadowRadius which separates the visible viewControllers during swiping back to the `RootViewController`.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: The problem is not creating the attributes, but getting finding the right view in the stack / having accept it an alternative shadowRadius.

Answer (score 0):

Best Way is add this extension in your class add extension at the end of your class and Add shadow as well corner radius to any view as well to navigation controller :)

```
extension UIView {


@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var borderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        if let color = layer.borderColor {
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let color = newValue {
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        } else {
            layer.borderColor = nil
        }
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.shadowRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowRadius = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var shadowOffset: CGSize {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOffset
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOffset = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var shadowColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        if let color = layer.shadowColor {
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let color = newValue {
            layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        } else {
            layer.shadowColor = nil
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: My problem is rather finding / calling the appropriate viewControllers view in the stack. Not how to create the attributes. Thanks!